# Download image from azure blob storage in winRt

Tags: azure, windows-8

I now about method **DownloadToStreamAsync** in [azure-sdk-winRT](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/microsoft-azure-api/Services/Storage/Lib/RT), but i can't implement this. How can i download image from blob storage, and save  in to a local folder?

Comment: Why can't you implement this? What have you tried?

Comment: because i have poor knowledges about stream in .net and winRt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below (very bare  bone implementation with no error checking):

```
        CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), true);
        var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("containername");
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("imagename.ext");//e.g myimage.png
        var file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("imagename.ext", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
        await stream.FlushAsync();
        stream.Dispose();
```

A few comments though:

- The example above writes to the "Pictures" library. You would need to ensure that your Windows 8 App has the capability defined for it.
- Try looking at shared access signature functionality instead of going the account credentials route especially if you're allowing users of your app to download images from your storage account.

Comment: Yes. You're basically reading byte stream from a blob and writing that stream to a file on your local machine. The stream could represent anything (binary data, text data etc.). For this example, I chose an image file.

Comment: How do you think, can we implement downloading data from blob storage with PathIO class in winRT?

Comment: I've no idea to be honest. Will try and look into it.